# Inline code and inline LaTeX, R Markdown Pandoc error 43

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I've run into this issue a couple times now, but whenever I try to include both inline LaTeX and inline R code in my Rmd file, I get Pandoc error 43. Never been able to find a workaround other than just manually adding in what the R code would have been.

````
---
title: "HW4"
date: "2/23/2018"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{amsmath}
  - \usepackage{amsthm}
output: 
  pdf_document
---

```{r}
x_bar <- 4
```

The blue line above is the true $\lambda = 4$, and the red line is our 
$\hat{\lambda}_{MLE} = \bar{x} = $ `r x_bar`.
````

Error:

```
l.192 \$ \hat{\lambda}

pandoc: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted
```

Comment: Try double `$$`, e.g., `$$\hat{\lambda}_{MLE} = \bar{x} = $$ `r x_bar` `. BTW: Your example is not working because x_bar was not defined.

Comment: @J_F thank you, my mistake on the variable (had to subset this from my code). Is there not a way to keep the LaTeX inline, though? The `$$` should stick the math in it's own line.

Comment: delete the space before the final `$`. It should read `... \bar{x} =$`

Answer (score 2):

Move the inline R expression inside the `$` symbols:

````
```{r}
x_bar <- 4
```

$\hat{\lambda}_{MLE} = \bar{x} = `r x_bar`$.
````

Rmd output:

[image]

Source: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/385#issuecomment-77309571

Alternatively, leave the inline R code outside but delete the trailing space before the second `$`.