# Rmarkdown inline latex error

Tags: knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I have an R function that returns text, including some LaTeX math mode, and I'm trying to use this text from an inline r chunk in an rmarkdown document. However, I get some quite strange behaviour regarding the use of math mode that I don't understand. It may be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942068/inline-code-and-inline-latex-r-markdown-pandoc-error-43).

## The following example works:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r print_function}
print_fun <- function(x){
  return(paste0("$\\mathrm{p}(\\beta < 0)$ > ", x))
}

x <- 0.5

```

Testing our printing function, we get `r print_fun(x)`.
````

Producing output

[image: working output]

## A small change breaks it

If I move the `$` symbol a few places to the right, in order to also include the `>` sign within the math mode block, the document no longer compiles:

````
```{r print_function}
print_fun <- function(x){
  return(paste0("$\\mathrm{p}(\\beta < 0) > $", x))
}

x <- 0.5

```
````

With the following error message:

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: \mathrm allowed only in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.137 ...g our printing function, we get \$\mathrm

Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted
```

This code works in an RSweave document, and I don't see why including the `>` symbol into math mode would have this effect.

## Closing math mode after the numerical reference compiles again

````
```{r print_function}
print_fun <- function(x){
  return(paste0("$\\mathrm{p}(\\beta < 0) > ", x, "$"))
}

x <- 0.5

```
````

Why?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is to do with the space before the `$` symbol in maths mode. From trial and error, this happens when the expression contains any maths function such as `\\mathrm{}`. So as minimal examples:

**Works:**

```
---
output: pdf_document
---

`r paste0("$\\mathrm{p}$")`

$\mathrm{p}$
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

`r paste0("$\\mathrm{p} $")`

$\mathrm{p} $
```

**Solution:**

In your case, you are best off pasting the `$` symbol after the value of the function:

```
print_fun <- function(x){
  return(paste0("$\\mathrm{p}(\\beta < 0) >", x, "$"))
}
```

This lets you have the space after the `>` symbol.